# Why doesn't my mongodb update operation not work? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following mongodb collection:

```
Channels [
{
  _id:'1'
  members:[
  {
    _id:'1'
    skipRounds:1
  },
  {
    _id:'2'
    skipRounds:3
  },       
  ]
},
{
  _id:'2'
  members:[
  {
    _id:'1'
    skipRounds:3
  },
  {
    _id:'2'
    skipRounds:5
  },       
  ]
},   
]
```

I am trying to be able to set the value on skipRounds for a specific user in a specific channel.

For example: I've tried to set skipRounds for the user with id 2 in channel with id 1 to 10

```
db.Channels.updateOne({
    '_id':'1',
    'members._id' : '2'
}, {
  $set: {'users.$.skipRounds': 10}
})
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update an element in a nested array try this:

```
db.Channels.update(
    {"_id" : "1", "members._id" : "2"},
    {
        $set : {"members.$.skipRounds" : 10}
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

replace  `$set: {'users.$.skipRounds': 10}` with `$set: {"members.skipRounds": 10}` example

```
db.Channels.updateOne({
    "_id":"1",
    "members._id" : "2"
}, {
  $set: {"members.skipRounds": 10}
})
```